# REGEXP_LIKE( email not working in Oracle PL SQL

Tags: database, oracle, rdbms

The regular expression I have created in the design of my database for verifying e-mail addresses is not working, even though I've read multiple Oracle forums which use the exact same expression. Every time I try to insert an email I get a check constraint violation.

```
CONSTRAINT check_email CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(
Email,'^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2-4}$'))
```

when trying INSERTS of the form:

```
INSERT INTO Member VALUES(0042, 'jasper@example.ie');
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue. The problem is use of '-' in your range for last alphabets after the period. Use a comma instead.

Consider:

Table:

```
    CREATE TABLE abc_1(abc_id NUMBER(10), email VARCHAR2(100));
```

Constraint(Same as yours):

```
    ALTER TABLE abc_1 ADD CONSTRAINT abc_email_check CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(Email,'^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2-4}$'));
```

Insert Statement:

```
    INSERT INTO abc_1 VALUES (1001, 'myEmail@service.c'); --Fails, expected
    INSERT INTO abc_1 VALUES (1001, 'myEmail@service.com'); --Fails, not expected
```

The problem is with the range specification {2-4}. Which should rather be {2,4}
Replace your check constraint as:

```
    ALTER TABLE abc_1 ADD CONSTRAINT abc_email_check CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(Email,'^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$'));

    INSERT INTO abc_1 VALUES (1001, 'myEmail@service.c'); --Fails, expected
    INSERT INTO abc_1 VALUES (1001, 'myEmail@service.com'); --Success, expected
```

When specifying range in regular expression, the way is {m,n}, where m is lower limit and n being the upper limit.

Comment: `@[A-Za-z0-9._-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$` is not sufficient, think about TLD's like [.museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.museum) for example.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - that is correct, but it should be a comment to the OP, not to this respondent. Rogue Coder identified correctly the error in the OP's code. Whether the "n" in {m,n} should be greater than 4 is a business question, not a coding question. (Who knows, perhaps the OP has a reason for limiting the last token to 4 characters - and in any case that is not related to this Answer.)

Comment: Agreed to both the comments. Obviously an email ID starting with '.' looks strange, but who knows!